# Update data records in raw text file

Tags: bash

I have a raw text file containing only 10 records.

```
1|word01
2|word02
3|word03
4|word04
5|word05
6|word06
7|word07
8|word08
9|word09
10|word10
```

If adding a new record, "word11", which apparently doesn't exist, it will stay on top, and all rows will be reindexed. Since the file should store only 10 records, the last one will be removed. The output is like:

```
1|word11
2|word01
3|word02
4|word03
5|word04
6|word05
7|word06
8|word07
9|word08
10|word09
```

If adding a new record that already existed, then it should be ordered to top and re-indexed all.

```
1|word04
2|word11
3|word01
4|word02
5|word03
6|word05
7|word06
8|word07
9|word08
10|word09
```

How to implement this manipulation in scripts? Any hint or help really appreciate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

usage ()
{
  echo usage: $0 RECORD FILE
  exit
}

[ $2 ] || usage
record=1
# print new record
echo "$record|$1" > k

# print other records
while IFS='|' read index value
do
  if [ ${value%$1} ]
  then
    (( record++ ))
    echo "$record|$value" >> k
  fi
done < "$2"

# trim to 10
head k > "$2"
rm k
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# command usage: cmd FILENAME NEWWORD
sed -i -e 's/[0-9]\+|\(.\+\)/\1/g' -e "/$2/d" $1
echo $2 > $1.tmp
cat $1 >> $1.tmp
nl -s '|' $1.tmp | head -10 | tr -d '[:blank:]' > $1
```